# How do I change the time zone in the interactive brokers API?

Tags: interactive-brokers, timezone

I am using the Interactive Brokers API, TWS release 974, with IBC and the ib_insync library.
I would like to change the time zone inside one of these, in order to get market data and history according to the America/New_York time zone.
I have already changed the machine's time zone to the needed one, but this has no effect on the IB results.
Where can I make the change to the proper time zone?

Answer (score 3):

The time zone is chosen by the user on the login screen before logging in.  Click more options under the login button.  A menu should appear like the image below.  Select your desired timezone there.

[image]

If you are looking to automate the log-in/log-out process check out this GitHub repo.  Be aware though that automated log in will not be possible if you have a 2-factor security device.  You would need to relax the security level of your account.  The program loads all credentials (including user timezone) from a `.ini` file.

https://github.com/IbcAlpha/IBC

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an automated way to do this.

Comment: @YuvalF It was not clear to me that that was your question.  I have edited my answer to include a link to a GitHub Repo that can do what you are asking.